# Subtracting viralnes

Tags: excel-formula

i have a yearly unit that i divide by a percentage to give me the monthly equivalent. I have a growth formula that increases the monthly unit to a yearly one month by month, how can i create a formula that give me the actual unit per month not the growth. Example
                           4
                           5
                           7
                           8 this is the growth but i what 5-4=1....
                                                           7-5=2...
=ROUND(Q59*$B$49,0) is how i get 4..5..6..7..8 how do i get to 1..2..1 in one formula . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you are looking for the incremental increase rather than the total increase. Without more information it is difficult to understand exactly what your looking for, but your formula sounds like it is multiplying over 100%. You want to multiply by the percentage of increase. so essentially what your doing is adding the beginning balance back in. Change your percentage in the cell to the increase and not the increase plus beginning.